# Chrome stuck in incognito

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Chrome is stuck in incognito from a previous setting that I configured from group policy and now it cannot be reverted. Group policy now lists the "Incognito mode availability" as not configured but it was previously set to forced. Changing the value has no effect.

I also have the "IncognitoModeAvailability" DWORD in the registry that is set to 2 but again changing this value has no effect.

Comment: Have you tried to delete all chrome profiles and completely reset the group policies ( connected to Chrome ) to their default values?

Comment: Yeah, I created a new user profile but the same problem persists.